# What's a convenient/appropriate way to override my document class' \paragraph style?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, document-classes, sections-paragraphs

The document class I'm using ([ieeetran](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/)) typesets paragraphs as in the following:

-------
[space here] a) The Paragraph Title In Italics:[space here]The quick brown fox jumped
over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy dog. 
-------

(actually, it doesn't matter exactly how they're typeset, since...)

I want paragraphs like in the article document class - with no indentation before the title, with boldface instead of italics, and with no numbering, thank you very much!

Besides creating a modified document class, what's a reasonable way to achieve this?

Comment: When submitting to IEEE, the chance is high that they revert your changes. A journal should have a consistent look, throughout.

Comment: @Johannes_B: But I don't want their 'structural' paragraph, I want an 'unstructued paragraph'

Comment: @HarishKumar: There's nothing particular to look at, it's not a bug or anything, more or a theoretical question.

Comment: A theoretical answer can be given in a comment, copy the definition of `paragraph`s  from the `cls` and redefine it in the document preamble. Or use package `titlesec` to do the redefinition with a nice interface. With a [MWE](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/), a ready to use solution can be presented.

Comment: The most reasonable way, barring other information, is: _simply use `article` if you want it to look like `article`_.

Comment: If you aren't submitting to IEEE, you are better off using a standard class (e.g. `article`). If you are submitting to IEEE, modifying the paragraph style is certainly pointless: journals don't allow authors to determine the way their articles are typeset. Content, sure. Format is the journal's business and they impose a consistent style for all articles.

Answer (score 1):

as Johannes_B said

```
\makeatletter
\def\theparagraph{\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```